# Apply Distance Buffer to Lat/Lon Points

Tags: python, buffer, csv

I have a CSV with three columns:

**CSV Sample:**

```
lat,lon,fhr
25.5,-61.7,0
26.1,-63.2,6
26.7,-64.7,12
27.3,-66.2,18
28.2,-67.7,24
29.1,-69.3,30
30.1,-70.6,36
31.3,-71.6,42
32.5,-72.7,48
33.3,-73.9,54
34.1,-74.5,60
```

I would like to plot these points and then apply a distance buffer of 120km to each lat/lon point using `python`.

Comment: I do not believe that the linked question is relevant to my question. The provided question is talking about shapefiles and GeoJSON

Comment: If not a shapefile or GeoJSON, what format do you want the output to be in?

Comment: Maybe GeoTIFF??